# How to use empty ELSE in batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have created a batch file that I'm usingbefore starting my React Native project. Before I build project, I have to delete folder 'build' from project folder, otherwise it's causing problems. So I wrote a code to check, if folder exist. If True, delete folder and continue code. Now, I would expect that if there is no folder (return False), the code will continue after If statement. But instead the CMD window just flash at screen and nothing's happening.

I have tried to add `ELSE ()`, but I got same result.

```
IF EXIST "C:\Users\+name+\git\actual\android\app\build" 
(@RD /S /Q "C:\Users\+name+\git\actual\android\app\build") 
&& cd C:\Users\+name+\git\actual && npm install && react-native start --reset-cache
```

I want: If there is folder, then delete it a continue with code.
If there isn't a folder, than just continue the code that is after `IF`/`ELSE` statement.

Comment: 1. There are too many line-breaks; is this really the code of your script? as it is written it should all be in a single line. 2. put `call` in front of `npm` since it is (usually) a batch file. 3. Replace `cd` by `cd /D` 4. `if <condition> command1 & command2` executes both commands conditionally; `(if <condition> command1) & command2` always executes the second command...

Comment: you can add an `exit` statement instead of your empty `else` statement, which would be more suitable for something like that (I also think that there is adifference between what you want and what is controling your `if`)

Comment: @damadam that kind of defeats the purpose of what OP is requesting. Please read the question again, especially the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you do not need to include an `Else` statement if you don't have a specific task to execute when the `If` is condition is not fulfilled.

As both `npm` and `react-native` are batch files, i.e `npm.cmd` and `react-native.cmd`, you should `Call` them if you want control returned to the batch file upon their completion. In the case you've supplied in your question code, you need at least `npm.cmd` to return upon its completion. The example below uses `Call` for both, so if your batch file ends at that line you can remove the second `Call`.

```bat
@CD /D "%UserProfile%\git\actual" 2>NUL||Exit /B 1
@If Exist "android\app\build\" RD /S /Q "android\app\build"
@Call npm install&&Call react-native start --reset-cache
```

If you wanted to run it as a single line, you can do that too:

```bat
@CD /D "%UserProfile%\git\actual" 2>NUL&&(RD /S/Q "android\app\build" 2>NUL&Call npm install&&react-native start --reset-cache)
```

This version has the second `Call` already removed.

---

Both examples have used the `%UserProfile%` variable to represent the profile of the current user, if you're running this as another user, you may wish to replace it, as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The if condition in the below example will only run `rd` if the folder exists and continue. But will skip the `rd` command if the directory does not exist.

```
set "mypath=C:\Users\+name+\git\actual\android\app\build"
if exist  %mypath" @RD /S /Q "%mypath%"
cd /d "C:\Users\+name+\git\actual"
call npm install && react-native start --reset-cache
```

You however do not need to call another process in a case like this where this would do exactly what you want:

```
rd /S /Q "C:\Users\+name+\git\actual\android\app\build">nul 2>&1
cd /d "C:\Users\+name+\git\actual"
call npm install && react-native start --reset-cache
```

If the folder does not exist it will simply return an error and we just redirect that error to `nul`.

**Sidenote!** if this is for your own user, you can replace the entire `C:\Users\+name+` part with the predefined environment variable `%userprofile%` this way a script can be distributed to other people without the need to make changes to the `username`

see `set userprofile` from cmd or `echo %userprofile%` or just `set` to see all predefined environment variables.

Comment: If `npm` is a .bat script as @aschipfl suggests, then it needs `CALL` before it or it will never return. Does `&&` overcome that?

Comment: @lit well, I was focusing on the OP's question, not the other parts really, but it does not really make a difference here, npm will launch locally and only once it completes wiith errorlevel 0 will it continue to the next command... but will update nevertheless.

Comment: In the second alternative code, you don't need the if statement.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException thanks bro, I just copied from the first example without looking at it again.

Comment: Instead of `C:\Users\+name+\ `, how about using `%USERPROFILE%\ `?

Comment: @lit I cannot assume it is the user's pofile.. he might be running the script as admin to do other profiles.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - Perhaps `runas` should be used if it is for another user.

Comment: @lit not if you are logged in as administrator. Chances are that the OP is running it as himself, but there are other possibilities, so I am focusing on the question itself.

Comment: @lit can we please cleanup comments here, it is getting cluttered. I will make mention of  the `userprofile` environment variable as well.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution to this is of the form:

```
if not somecondition goto stage2

:stage1
command1
command2

:stage2
realwork1
realwork2
```

Comment: Well, that is a quite a workaround... easier would just be `if exist filename del filename` the next command will be initiated regardless so just 1 line needed instead of three.. plus no labels required.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard For sure, but this can be extended to do multiple things in the 'exists' case. I'll make it clearer what my intention was.